# How to know if page is called by get or post method inside of razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

i want to use the same view for create and display the same object.
if the page is called by get method it show you a form for edit the object.
if the page is called by post method it show you the value of the object.

i've already done it by using 2 different view.
and trying with model state.

i want something like

```
@if(Method =="GET"){
  // form for edit.
}
else{
  // show data.
}
```

i've tried

```
        @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)//this is always true
        {
            @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductID);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductDescription);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductPrice);
                <input type="submit" value="registra"/>
            }
        }
        else
        {
               <p>@Model.ProductID</p>
               <p>@Model.ProductName</p>
               <p>@Model.ProductDescription</p>
               <p>@Model.ProductPrice</p>
        }
```

if in the controller i use 2 different views it work well but i cannot use the same view because

Comment: i've made it work using ViewBag.
in the action method i've just add ViewBag.Method="GET"; or ViewBag.Method="POST".
in the view i've just make @if(ViewBag.Method=="GET"){...}

Comment: Why do you want just one view? Views should be  as devoid of logic as possible. It makes no sense to branch the entire view over two different possibilities. If there's some HTML or content that needs to be shared between the two different views, then factor out that shared content into a partial, and reference the partial in both.

Answer (score 0):

if its a post method then the model will not have ID. and you should check it in controller /method level